# TeXnicCenter quick build

Tags: compiling, texniccenter

I use TeXnicCenter to build my LaTeX documents under Windows 7.

I usually have 3-4 tabs open in TeXnicCenter corresponding to the different sections of my document.
To build my document I have to go to the first tab (the index of my file), build, and then go back to the old tab where I was editing (one of the sections).

Is there a smarter way of doing this? 
I would like a hotkey that just move to the first tab and compile. 
<kbd>F5</kbd> only compiles the current tab, it is not aware if it is the index or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a *project* rather than just working with regular files. Each project has a "main file", so that when you "build the project", it builds the main file, which may be different from the actively selected window/tab.

Start a new project (menu option `File` > `New Project`) and specify the main file or change the main file for an existing project (menu option `Project` > `Properties`):

[image]

Now use the "Build and View Output" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> rather than the usual "Build and View Current File" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Werner, you’re too kind. ;-) Actually creating a project is _the only way_ for what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 6):

You can also convert a regular TeX input file to a project as follows.

### Step 1

Let `trash.tex` be your regular TeX input file. Open it as shown in the following figure.

[image]

### Step 2

Choose `Project` and click `Create with active file as main file` as follows.

[image]

### Step 3

Click `OK` and done!

[image]

Now you can TeXify the project with one-click.